# How to list all Matrix Blocks from anywhere, using a slug?

Tags: matrix

I came across a specific situation where I needed to list out all the values within a collection of Matrix fields on a single entry page.

More specifically, I had a single entry that needed multiple team groups, each with the name, role, and description of various people. I then wanted to list them all out anywhere on the site (single or entry pages).

Hope this solution helps people out. Feel free to critique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{% cache %}
  {% set entry = craft.entries.slug('team').last() %}
  {% for field in entry.getFieldLayout().getFields() %}
    {% if field.getField().type == "Matrix" %}
      {% set fieldHandle = field.getField().handle %}
      {% set matrixBlocks = entry.__get(fieldHandle).find() %}
      {% for block in matrixBlocks %}
        {{ block.team_name }}
      {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
{% endcache %}
```